# how to create a database in MS Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have tried and searched a lot on internet but found no way of creating a database in Ms Visual Studio 2013.

I am learning basics in c#. I have SQL Server 2008 at bakend.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx

Comment: Do you have SQL Server 2008 "frontend" namely Management Studion (SSMS) ?

Answer (score 12):

If you not only want to create a database, but plan longer development using Visual Studio, then create new project of database type (File -> New Project, then select Templates, Other Languages, SQL Server, SQL Server Database Project). You will be able to use favorite version control system, make database releases in form of DACPAC and BACPAC packages, easily create upgrade scripts, do schema compare and so on. This is included in Visual Studio 2013 and available as separate free addon for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 (so called [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx)). Definitely take your time to acquaint with it.

This is new, developer-oriented way of professional database development. SQL Server Management Studio is more administrative tool than a full blown developer tool.

Comment: I can't find this template. Not installed, not online. Professional 13, update 1. What am I doing wrong? All I want to do is to create a small MVC project with a database.

Answer (score 3):

In VS 2013 go to New Project > Installed > Templates > Other Languages > SQL Server.  There you can create a new Database Project and use that.